# How to set a breakpoint in a setter method in IntelliJ IDEA that is generated with Lombok?

Tags: java, hibernate, intellij-idea, lombok

Is there a way in **IntelliJ IDEA** to set a **breakpoint** in a setter method that is generated by **Lombok**?

This would be very useful in certain debugging scenarios, e.g. to see when the setter is called from a framework like Hibernate.

In fact, the generated setter methods are displayed in the structure view of IntelliJ IDEA (Lombok plugin in use). But I've not found a way to set a breakpoint via the context menu or such.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In my understanding you can't do that because lombok is mutating your bytecode in a way that mutated code doesn't have line numbers for auto-generated parts.

This is done on purpose to always have your source code lines match your bytecode. It they doesn't match, you'll may get caught in a situation when you placing your breakpoints on a line but execution didn't stop or stops somewhere else (because of line numbers mismatching).

But in exchange Lombok loses the ability to debug generated code (you can't place breakpoint on a line without line number). You have to rely on a fact that generated code is correct.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be a reasonable explanation. With respect to debugging code generated by Lombok: I don't doubt that this code is correct. However, if I would be able to stop in the debugger when a Lombok getter is called, it would make the debugging of the calling code easier - especially when these classes are called from frameworks like Hibernate.

Comment: You can use delombok to generate the java code that resembles the code lombok uses under the hood, and set breakpoints in the generated code.

Comment: This is not true.

Answer (score 21):

As a workaround you may use **Java Field Watchpoint**. In such a case every access/modification of the field will result in a break point.

The disadvantage of this approach is getting a thread suspension both when you access/modify the field directly or using getter/setter methods.

However, when you catch a breakpoint using setter methods, IDEA also shows a parameter (with the same name as the field used for the watch point) in Variables window and the breakpoint is shown not in the field's line, but in the class' line.

[image: Setter Break point]

The following short description, how to create a field watch point, was copied from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/creating-field-watchpoints.html:

1. On the main menu, choose Run | View Breakpoints, or press Ctrl+Shift+F8.
2. In the Breakpoints dialog box that opens, click add (plus icon) button.
3. Select Field Watchpoint from the drop-down list: "Java Field Watchpoints"
4. In the Add Field Watchpoint dialog box that opens, specify the following:
   **Fully qualified name of a class** that contains the desired field. You can type it manually, or click browse Button, and find the desired class by name, or from the project.
   **Field name**. You can type it manually, or click browse Button and select the desired field from the list of fields in the selected class.
5. Also, you may set other options like Field access (for getters) or Field modification (for setters)

Answer (score 8):

Breakpoints work on implicit funcions. `delombok` feature allows generate implicit implementation (After debugging you could/should revert maiden changes). To make implicit implementation just right-click on class name and select the following menu line:

[image]

Comment: This is probably the ideal solution. While you can use field watchpoints, they are incredibly slow, and if you don't have access to the source code, this is a non-issue.

Answer (score 6):

I win:

- Run -> View Breakpoints (or Ctrl+Shift+F8)
- Click '+' (or Alt+Ins)
- Select '1. Java Method Breakpoint'
- Either painfully enter fully qualified classname or a pattern such as '*.MyClass'
- Enter method name
- Click OK

Only took me 6 years :-)

On Eclipse: right click on the method in the Class outline or Type hierarchy and select 'Toggle method breakpoint'.

Answer (score 0):

In the structure-view select the setter and right-click. The popup-menu contains a menu item "Toggle Method Breakpoint" (the same way you can set a break-point in a default-constructor in a class without a default-constructor in it's java-code)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately this does not work for Lombok-generated methods - at least for me. While method breakpoints for ordinary "handwritten" Java methods are listed in the IDEA's breakpoints dialog, this is not true for Lombok-generated ones.