# How to debug lombok objects

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, lombok

Does anyone know how to set a breakpoint in the following `Person.toString()` when using Eclipse or IntelliJ IDEA?

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.ToString;

@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class Person {
    private String lastName;
    private String firstName;
}
```

---

EDIT:

If possible, I want to stop only when `toString()` is called.

Comment: Use a [field breakpoint](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fbreakpoints%2Fref-access_option.htm) or "delombok" the class

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24751922/how-to-set-a-breakpoint-in-a-setter-method-in-intellij-idea-that-is-generated-wi?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a breakpoint in a setter method in IntelliJ IDEA that is generated with Lombok?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24751922/how-to-set-a-breakpoint-in-a-setter-method-in-intellij-idea-that-is-generated-wi)

Comment: If possible, I want to stop only when `toString()` is called.

Comment: You could extend `Person` class and override toString() method, and breakpoint on that.

Comment: Umm, If possible, I don't want to change source code.

Comment: RC is right: "Delombok" is probably the most easiest way: Use main menu Refactor->Delombok->@ToString. The resulting class should even hot-swap fine in a running debugger session because it is the same as before.

Comment: Use "Delombock" feature as it is suggested in the above comments, then after you finish your work just CTRL+Z or `git revert` and will end up with the original source code

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem **Not using Lombok is evil.** Without it, my code would grow by maybe 50%. IDE code generation is evil as it gets obsolete quickly.

Comment: @maaartinus Lombok makes debugging much more difficult - it's hard to step through the generated code or put breakpoints in it.  It also makes many of the standard refactoring operations that come with your IDE fail spectacularly.  Debugging and refactoring are important parts of programming, so if you use Lombok, you're shooting yourself in the foot.  Frankly, I don't care if my code is 50% bigger - this is a small price to pay for being free of the evil.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Step thought the generated code? Seriously? Why should I *waste my time* on this??? I don't step into bytecode either. +++ I'm using Lombok intensively since the very beginning and I never needed this (I did need a breakpoint on generated stuff, but never even thought about going inside). +++ Refactoring has some minor problems, but I can't recall when it recently really failed (months or years ago). I'm not using IDEA, maybe that's the difference? Maybe I'm missing some advanced refactorings? Honestly, for me, debugging works at 100% and refactoring is slightly worse.

Comment: Thank you, everyone! your comments are helpful.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're asking about both Eclipse and IntelliJ IDEA, and the answers are very different:

- In Eclipse, right click on the method in the Members view and use "Toggle method breakpoint".
- In IDEA, <strike>there is [no solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24751922/581205), but</strike> there are good workarounds (see below) and there's a solution described in the comment by @PeterVerhas.

> Umm, If possible, I don't want to change source code.

You're surely using [version control](https://git-scm.com/), so nothing can go wrong, right? If not, then please start using it ASAP as I can't imagine any work without it.

The workaround is very easy despite having several steps:

1. First, use version control to make sure you don't lose the current state (I usually just move everything down using "Rescan" and "Stage Changed" in [git-gui](http://www.craftitonline.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/Selection_165.png)).
2. Do "Refactor" -> "Delombok" -> "@ToString" (IDEA only) and any other changes you want for debugging.
3. Debug.
4. Undo the changes in editor (if possible).
5. Last, use version control to view the state of the working tree ("Rescan" in git-gui) and possibly to revert the unwanted changes ("Commit" -> "Revert changes" in git-gui) and/or to verify the state of the working tree.

Apart from debugging, which usually takes rather long, each of the steps takes one or two seconds. So there's hardly any overhead. Trust me, I do temporary code changes a few times a day.

Comment: Ah, I understand we cannot use "Toggle method breakpoint" on IntelliJ because IntelliJ Lombok plugin cannot show the methods that are refactored by Lombok. Thank you!

Comment: I am currently looking at IntelliJ (version below) and in the debugger breakpoint window it is possible to add a so called "Java Method Breakpoint". You have to copy paste the fully qualified name of the class (copy reference) and type the name of the method. It works with `toString()` in Lombok. So there is no need to delombok in case of IntelliJ. Maybe this is a newer feature.

IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1.3 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-191.7479.7, built on May 21, 2019

Comment: @PeterVerhas I'm currently using Eclipse only, but I'm glad to hear the Lombok support in Idea has got better. Feel free to edit my answer accordingly.